# List doesnot have TreeList

Tags: java, collections

There is a `Map` implementation called `TreeMap` and a `Set` implementation called `TreeSet`. Why is there no `TreeList` implementation of the `List` interface?

This was an interview question.

Comment: A `List` is an indexed, expandable, collection. What would a `TreeList` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to understand what is the purpose of these implementation like both these TreeMap and Treeset are implementation of SortedSet and SortedMap is used for sorting purpose but we have Collections.sort(List) which can be implied on List for sorting hence not TreeList is not required in List

Comment: Not quite. What if I want a `SortedList`? Calling `Collections.sort()` after each `add` would be rather ... inefficient.

Comment: @Boris the spider, Please refer Head First Java you will get it cleared

Comment: Get what cleared? Maintaing a sorted list by using `Collections.sort` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Because a list is an index-based data structure, and trees are no index-based data structures. That's the most basic and clear reason.